# Pulling Facebook photos onto an external website

Tags: django, facebook, photo

I'm doing a job for Company A. I've just built their website in Django but now they want to add a social photo management aspect to the site (in that other people can upload).

The only way I know of doing this (having done it before) is through Flickr. You can set up a group and have it so anybody can add photos to it. And pull out the latest with RSS. But let's be honest, Facebook is far more popular and my client wants this feature heavily used by his clientèle.

They have a Facebook page and the power to open it up so anybody can add their photos to it... But how can I pull those photos back to the website?

Comment: I think you need to explain more what you mean by 'pull those photos back to the website'. If the URLs are public and the site doesn't care about referers then just use the URL in an <img> tag. If you want to hoik the image files over to your server then import urllib2 and work from there. Is either of those what you want?

Comment: That's an interesting idea that might work on a technical level although I'm fairly sure there's a copyright issue in there at some point (because we'll mostly be sourcing the photos from third parties that upload them to the Facebook page) and it's almost certainly against Facebook's Terms of Service.

Comment: To clarify what I'm really after: A Facebook sanctioned API or RSS feed of the latest photos on a Facebook page that I can parse and embed on our website.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's query language can do this (like the RSS sends data to you from Flickr) for users of FB pages, and there are some Javascripts for making them viewable and interactive on external web pages.

For example:

http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html

http://www.alexanderinteractive.com/blog/2012/03/display-facebook-photos-on-your-website-with-galleria/

Good luck!
Terry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I recall that the Flock Web Browser had the capability of loading a stream of new videos/photos on the top of the brower's media stream bar - perhaps you can sneak a peek into the inner workings it uses to accomplish this task.

I know that you can start reading the RSS feed of a Facebook Page itself now, perhaps just a little parsing is all you need: http://www.allfacebook.com/facebook-pages-rss-2010-01